# What produce in Central Texas works in hanging towers?

Tags: aquaponics

I am located near Austin. Using the hanging tower approach, what produce tends to work best in this style of aquaponics system?

Comment: This isn't an answer.  I've no experience with tower systems, and you've probably discovered from your own research that the solanaceous/nightshade/ cucurbit family will do well on trellis if you can support the fruit.  I'd be interested to know what you've learned since you asked this question.

Comment: YOu need to clarify your question.  Detail, or provide references to the 'hanging tower approach'

Comment: I agree, I don't think people will know what hanging towers are.  Why would you start with a technology before the produce.  It would seem to me, you would have something you want to grow, and then figure out what would be the best way to grow it. It's sort of like asking what is the best stuff to haul in a 4-axle eight wheel dump truck...  Unless you inherited it, or bought a property with a 'hanging tower' on it...

Comment: Does anyone else get shivers from the words 'Texas hanging towers'?

Answer (score 2):

Tomatoes sound like a good start, easy to grow and they like the structure you could provide.